# Matching multiple criteria (matrix transpose)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

In Excel, I want to lookup/index a table that matches both the `station_number` and the `month`.

Say I have the following data on sheet1:

```
           Jan Feb Mar Apr May
station1    1   8   17  14  0
station5    4   5   8   10  14
station7    18  7   4   9   10
station10   5   11  15  12  4
```

On sheet2, I want to fill in the details below:

```
    Station1    Station2    Station3    Station4    Station5    Station6
Jan   1                                                4    
Feb   8                                                5    
Mar   17                                               8    
Apr   14                                               10   
May   0                                                14
```

What is the formula I use in order to look up sheet1 and complete sheet2? I tried `=VLOOKUP(B1&A2,'Sheet1'!A1:F5,2,FALSE)` which is obviously incorrect. Any help would be great.

Comment: You can use match() to find the position of each of the two headers, then feed those numbers into INDEX() to pull back the required value.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but how do I match the station AND the date? Something like: =INDEX('Sheet1'!B2:F5,MATCH(Sheet2!B1,'Sheet1'!A2:A5,0))

Comment: Or this {=INDEX('Sheet1'!B2:F5,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!B1='Sheet1'!A2:A5)*(B2='Sheet1'!B1:E1),0))} but I just get "N/A"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet1!$B$2:$F$5,MATCH(J$1,sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,0),MATCH($I2,sheet1!$B$1:$F$1,0)),"")
```

in sheet2 where your `1` is (assumed to be J2), and copy across and down to suit.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Hlookup something like following for column station1:

```
=+HLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$F$2,2,0)
```

It should work and hope this helps also.

where sheet1 is the actual source of your input data, but offcourse with every column the references must be change so for station10 column formula would be:

```
=+HLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$F$5,5,0)
```